# Como unificar regitros com angularjs no ngrepeat repetindo registros de determinado campo

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-repeat

O back-end me retorna um json com os registros que preciso mostrar na view. Um "contrato" pode ter mais de uma "demanda" e quando isso ocorre, repete-se (no banco de dados por outra aplicação) o registro do contrato modificando apenas a FK (chave estrangeira) relacionada a "demanda". Ex.: contrato X pode estar na demanda 1,4,5 ao mesmo tempo.

Uso o ng-repeat para mostrar os contratos na tela. Há uma coluna "demanda" onde (pelo ng-class) o ícone fica azul caso o contrato esteja em alguma demanda.

**Problema**: como no banco de dados se repete o contrato em vários registros mudando apenas o campo demanda, esses registros também chegam repetidos no json. Há como unificar essas repetições numa única linha e repetir apenas as demandas deste contrato? Por exemplo: o contrato no json abaixo está nas demandas 3,2 e 4. Então gostaria de mostrar apenas uma vez o contrato e pintar os 3 ícones de azul referente as demandas em que o mesmo contrato está relacionado.

json (esses 3 índices abaixo se referem ao mesmo contrato, porém com demandas diferentes):

```js
4: SIG_UF: "SP"
VLR_CNTR: "30000.00"
idTipoDemanda: 3
numeroContrato: 30001

5: SIG_UF: "SP"
VLR_CNTR: "30000.00"
idTipoDemanda: 2
numeroContrato: 30001

6: SIG_UF: "SP"
VLR_CNTR: "30000.00"
idTipoDemanda: 4
numeroContrato: 30001
```

HTML do ícone:

```html
<span class="inline-block">
  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.idTipoDemanda==3, 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': contrato.idTipoDemanda!=3}"></i>
                            
  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.idTipoDemanda==8, 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': contrato.idTipoDemanda!=8}"></i>

  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.idTipoDemanda==2, 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': contrato.idTipoDemanda!=2}"></i>

  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.idTipoDemanda==4, 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': contrato.idTipoDemanda !=4}"></i>
                                
  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.idTipoDemanda==5, 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': contrato.idTipoDemanda!=5}"></i>
</span>
```

Como os ícones são mostrados:

[image: Como os ícones são mostrados]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possibilidade que eu vejo para resolver o seu problema é criar um array de objetos de contrato, cuja chave seria o código do contrato. Basta percorrer o JSON que você possui e ir montando os objetos conforme a necessidade.

A estrutura de dados seria a seguinte:

```
[
  {
    SIG_UF: "SP",
    numeroContrato: 30001,
    VLR_CNTR: "30000.00",
    tiposDemanda: [
       2,3,4
    ]
  }
]
```

E o HTML seria alterado para

```
<span class="inline-block">
  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(3), 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': !contrato.tiposDemanad.includes(3)}"></i>

  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(8), 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': !contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(8)}"></i>

  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(2), 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': !contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(2)}"></i>

  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contratotiposDemanda.includes(4), 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': !contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(4)}"></i>

  <i ng-class="{'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-primary': contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(5), 'mi mi--fiber-manual-record tx-grey': !contrato.tiposDemanda.includes(5)}"></i>
</span>
```

Lembre de ter cuidado ao utilizar o includes, pois para retornar true as variáveis devem ser do mesmo tipo.

Comment: Obrigado João Paulo, solucionou o problema.